# Как поставить прослушку ipv6 адреса для двух доменов в nginx?

Tags: nginx, ipv6

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы два домена были доступны через IPV6. Есть два конфига: первого сайта и второго.

В обеих файлах (за исключением `server_name` и настроек ssl) находятся следующие строки:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

  ...
}

server {
  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;

  ...
}
```

Есть ещё третий конфиг для обработки запросов непосредственно на самом айпи сервера:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

  server_name localhost;

  root /var/www/http;
}
```

При попытке запуска сервера, nginx ругается и говорит, что `duplicate listen options for [::]:443`. Не понимаю, почему дубликат, если я хочу слушать ipv6 на обеих сайтах. Как исправить ситуацию, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Может, есть какой-то третий конфиг? Из предыдущего вашего вопроса, например)

Comment: здравствуйте) есть ещё default, отредактировал вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

`ipv6only=on` можно указать только один раз для конкретной пары ip:port